# I am working on a school project and I am getting two errors and I have no idea how to fix them, any ideas?

Tags: c++

Error   1   error C2628: 'question' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)

Error   2   error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

```
/*
The Great Quiz Show Game

by

Seth Alpha
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class question

int main();
{
cout << "***********************" << endl;
cout << "*                     *" << endl;
cout << "* The Great Quiz Show *" << endl;
cout << "*                     *" << endl;
cout << "*         by          *" << endl;
cout << "*                     *" << endl;
cout << "*      Seth A----     *" << endl;
cout << "*                     *" << endl;
cout << "***********************" << endl;
cout << endl;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can give! :)

Comment: What are you trying to do with `class question`?

Comment: I was about to add a class for something, but then I tried to run the part that I already have there so I suppose it is useless. Sorry about that.

Comment: It would help to look at some examples of how to create a class.  What you have defined is absolutely nothing after the declaration.

Comment: @Salpha Then remove it and try to compile again.

Comment: @NathanOliver He is trying to ask a question. Without class question he had not a question.:)

Comment: After removing the class it fixed my first error, that was just a careless mistake sorry about that, but the second error is still there.

Comment: @Salpha you have `int main();` instead of `int main()`

Comment: That fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(); should be int main() {
```

P.S. You don't need to include the string library unless you're declaring a string variable